# ¿Cómo debería dejar de checkear datos de un json con python?

Tags: python, json

Sucede que tengo un json, con la data de unos IDs de usuarios de Discord, y estoy intentando hacer de que python reconozca cuando un usuario está en la lista, y que si no está, este le cree una lista. El problema radica en que cuando ejecuto el código que tengo, reconoce cuando está el ID en la lista y ejecuta el código correspondiente, pero sigue buscando y con ello cuando no reconoce el ID del usuario en la siguiente lista, lo toma como si el usuario no está en ninguna y le crea su propia lista cuando este no lo necesita. Modifiqué un poco el código para que sea más legible, usando prints en vez de la edición del archivo JSON:

```
for k,l in enumerate(z[g]['user'][i]['kissed']):
    usersid = z[g]['user'][i]['userid']
    if otherguyid in usersid:
        print("Aquí sí")
    else:
        print("Aquí no") """En el caso del código original, 
lo que hace es igual crear una lista al usuario faltante cuando esta ya existe"""
```

**Output:**

```
Aquí sí
Aquí sí
Aquí no
```

Cabe recalcar que las letras como "g" o "i" son índices, hechos con un bucle for in enumerate(z[elemento]). Por cierto, desconozco por qué en el output sale dos veces "Aquí sí", siendo que el usuario correcto se encuentra solamente en una lista, así que también busco la solución de ello a pesar de que no es lo que me complica principalmente.

EDIT: Me pidieron un ejemplo del JSON, así que aquí va:

```
[
{
    "user": [
        {
            "userid": "123456789123456789",
            "kissed": [
                {
                    "kissid": "123456789123456789",
                    "times": 74
                },
                {
                    "kissid": "123456789123456789",
                    "times": 18
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "user": [
        {
            "userid": "123456789123456789",
            "kissed": [
                {
                    "kissid": "123456789123456789",
                    "times": 66
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Comment: Lo que buscas es la palabra break. Esa palabra finaliza "a la fuerza" el bucle for actual.

Comment: Hay un problema, y es que si cambio el orden de las listas va a finalizar el bucle antes de que el programa pueda leer que el usuario en realidad si está.

Comment: Pon un ejemplo reducido del json y qué es lo que se debe obtener en la salida.